# how to remove a GTK window

Tags: c#, gtk

I created a GTK window, now I don't need it anymore, so how do I remove it from memory?

I suppose that calling `Hide()` and then just removing all references will not really make GC clean all stuff, so is there some extra function I need to call so that I completely remove the window from memory?

I suppose that `Dispose()` is a good candidate, but I don't know what it actually does since there is little documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gtk_widget_destroy()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-destroy).

Anyway, if you are using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [1] the bindings should automatically take care of object destruction when the last reference goes out of scope.

[1] I don't know anything of C#, but at least with [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) this is the case.